# How to add links to resources without any entities in Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have a very loosely couplet system that takes about any json payload and saves in a mongo colection.

There are no entities to expose as resouces, but only controller endpoints
eg.

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> publish(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> jsonBody) {
.. save the body in mongo
....}
```

I still want to build a hypermedia driven app. with links for navigation and paging.

The controller therefor implements ResourceProcessor

```
public class PublicationController implements ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> {
....
 @Override
public RepositoryLinksResource process(RepositoryLinksResource resource) {
    resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(PublicationController.class).getPublications()).withRel("publications"));
    return resource;
}
```

The problem is that the processor never gets called ??
Putting @EnableWebMvc on a configuration class solves it (the processor gets called), but firstly that should not be necessary, and secondary the format of HAL links seems broken

eg. gets formattet as a list

```
links: [
{
"links":[
    {
        "rel":"self",
        "href":"http://localhost:8080/api/publications/121212"
    },
    {
        "rel":"findByStartTimeBetween",
        "href":"http://localhost:8080/api/publications/search/findStartTimeBetween?timeStart=2015-04-10T13:44:56.437&timeEnd=2015-04-10T13:44:56.439"
    }
]
```

}

Are there alternatives to @enableWebMvc so the processor gets called ?

Currently I'm running Spring boot v. 1.2.3

Comment: You're using the @Controller annotation, right? Can you include the annotations you're using on that class?

Comment: Yeah - I'm using the @RestController annotation

Comment: It'd be helpful to be able to see the entire controller class, in particular the getPublications() method.

Comment: sure - I'll add it when I'm back at work monday. And Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that the answer was quite simple. 
The problem was that I had static content (resources/static/index.html) 
This will suppress the hypermedia links from the root.
Moving the static content made everything thing work great.